# How to make a number using Bitwise Operators in PHP

Tags: php, int, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

0Using `PHP`, I want to make a number that consists of the given number of 1s in binary system. For example, if bits number is 5, the output would be `11111` in binary system, i.e. `2^5 -1`.

I am aware that it could be done by:

```
 pow( 2, ( 32 - $netmask ) ) - 1;
```

But I am afraid it would be time consuming, So I thought maybe it is better to use bitwise operators. for example:

```
 (~0 >> $netmask) << $netmask
```

But I am not sure if it works in `PHP`.

(`$netmask` is the number of 0 digits before the first 1 and it is between 0 and 32. The number of 1s is equal to `32-$netmask`)

Is the second formula correct? and Is it better than the first one?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please can you explain why you think the first formula would be time consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following shift trick will do it.

```
function bitnum($num){
    return ~(~0<<$num)
}
```

Check the [**Fiddle**](http://codepad.org/QdJTskkr)